# PyQt4 signals and slots - QToolButton

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, signals-slots

In PyQt4 I have a main window which when the settings button is clicked opens the settings dialog

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import ui_Design, ui_Settings_Design

class MainDialog(QtGui.QMainWindow, ui_Design.Ui_arbCrunchUI):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.settingsBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showSettings())

    def showSettings(self):
        dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
        dialog.ui = SettingsDialog()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.exec_()
```

The above works and my SettingsDialog is displayed but I cant get the  setPageIndex to work

```
class SettingsDialog(QtGui.QDialog, ui_Settings_Design.Ui_SettingsDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SettingsDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.bookSettingsBtn.clicked.connect(self.setPageIndex)

   @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
   def setPageIndex(self):
       print 'selected'
       self.settingsStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

The bookSettingsBtn is a QToolButton

```
self.bookSettingsBtn = QtGui.QToolButton(self.navigationFrame)
```

And the settingsStackedWidget is a QStackedWidget

```
self.settingsStackedWidget = QtGui.QStackedWidget(SettingsDialog)
```

At this point I am pretty confused on signals and slots and nothing I have read clears this up - if anyone can point out what I am doing wrong above and also potentially direct me to a good (beginners) guide / tutorial on signals and slots it would be greatly appreciated

I would also like to know how to make setPageIndex work as follows:

```
def setPageIndex(self, selection):
     self.settingsStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(selection)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing the following, but that's the issue:

```
def showSettings(self):
    dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    dialog.ui = SettingsDialog()
    dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.exec_()
```

`SettingsDialog` itself is a proper `QDialog`. You don't need to instantiate another `QDialog`.

Right now, you're creating an empty `QDialog` and then populate it with the same ui as `SettingsDialog` (i.e. `setupUi(dialog)`), then you show this dialog. But... The signal connection is for `SettingsDialog`, and the dialog you're showing doesn't have that.

Basically, you don't need that extra `QDialog` at all. The following should be enough:

```
def showSettings(self):
    dialog = SettingsDialog()
    dialog.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So here is an example how you pass an argument to a slot

from functools import partial

```
# here you have a button bookSettingsBtn:
self.bookSettingsBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("settings")
self.bookSettingsBtn.clicked.connect(partial(self.setPageIndex, self.bookSettingsBtn.text()))

@pyqtSlot(str) # this means the function expects 1 string parameter (str, str) 2 string parameters etc.
def setPageIndex(self, selection):
    print "you pressed button " + selection
```

In your case the argument would be an int. Of course you have to get the value from somewhere
and then put it in the partial part as the argument (here I just used the text of the button),
but you can use int, bool etc. Just watch the slot signature.

Here is a tutorial that helped me:
http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt work in my program. The setPageIndex method is not called. I changed the connection line to include an additional parenthesis at the end, I assume this is what you meant?: self.bookSettingsBtn.clicked.connect(partial(self.setPageIndex, self.bookSettingsBtn.text()))

Comment: Yes I've edited it. I forgot the last parenthesis. Why is setPageIndex not called? It should work like that. Try another slot without any parameter and test if that works to see where the failure is (like define @pyqtSlot() def bla(self): print 'bla'. The tutorial is helpful.

Comment: I already read that tutorial but I guess I have a problem elsewhere because as you pointed out it should work like this! With self.bookSettingsBtn.clicked.connect(self.printBlah()). 'blah' prints immediately when the settingsDialog is initialized rather than clicked the button then I get the following error:     self.bookSettingsBtn.clicked.connect(self.printBlah())
TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'NoneType'. If I add lambda as I did in the main dialog then nothing happens when the button is clicked???

Comment: Typo!: .... .connect(self.printBla) <-- without parenthesis (This typo happened to me a lot)

Answer (score 0):

Hey here I have a fully running example (just copy paste it in a python file and run it):
Maybe this helps you. It's a small example but here you see how it works.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from functools import partial

class MyForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(parent)
        button1 = QPushButton('Button 1')
        button2 = QPushButton('Button 2')
        button1.clicked.connect(partial(self.on_button, button1.text()))
        button2.clicked.connect(partial(self.on_button, button1.text()))

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button1)
        layout.addWidget(button2)

        main_frame = QWidget()
        main_frame.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(main_frame)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_button(self, n):
        print "Text of button is: " + str(n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: This is very clear and helpful, thx. It doesn't really help with my program though - could the problem be how I am importing my button from another module and calling self.btn? This is the only difference I can see. I also dont understand why the connect signal is called with the __init__ function rather than when the btn is clicked - lambda solved this with the settingsBtn in the MainWindow but doesnt do so in the settings window

Comment: Did it work? If yes and I helped you accept the answer please. The problem was I could not run your code because I don't have the modules ui_settings, etc.

Comment: No it still doesn't work. I think the signal is not getting passed, as when I include () on the slot 'blah' prints then I get an error. Without the () nothing happens on btn click

Comment: Is this your whole code? Because I can't run it like that (ui_settings etc. I don't have)

Comment: There is about 1500 lines - do I paste it here as an answer?

Comment: @lorgan you can share your code on pastebin or dropbox. You shouldnt post anything as an Answer unless it IS an answer to this post's question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

So I dont really understand why but changing the way the settingsDialog is called from the MainWindow has fixed my problem. I guess the parent window needed to be specified??:

```
class MainDialog(QtGui.QMainWindow, ui_Design.Ui_arbCrunchUI):
....
    def showSettings(self):
        self.settingsDialog = QtGui.QDialog(self)
        self.settingsDialog.ui = SettingsDialog(self)
        self.settingsDialog.ui.show()

class SettingsDialog(QtGui.QDialog, ui_Settings_Design.Ui_SettingsDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SettingsDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.bookSettingsBtn.clicked.connect(partial(self.setPageIndex, 1))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def setPageIndex(self, selection):
        self.settingsStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(selection)
```

Comment: Ok. So the problem was not the slot. So I answered the question you asked (partial, please accept my answer :D), but why it didn't work I could not figure out because of the lack of important code.